# Complexity of a particular problem

Tags: np-complete

Let $G_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ for $i$ from $1$ to $r$ and $j$ from $1$ to $s>r$ be fixed.

Is deciding $\exists u_1,u_2,\dots,u_r$ that satisfies the following formula **NP-Complete**? $$\otimes_{j=1}^{s}\oplus_{i=1}^{r}u_i \otimes G_{ij} = 1$$

($a\oplus b=0 \iff a=b$ and $a \otimes b = 1 \iff a=b=1$)

What if it is given the set of $G_{ij} = 1$ for each $j$ has cardinality that satisfies one of the two cases:

$(1)$ Cardinality atmost $d$ for some constant $d > 0$?

$(2)$ Cardinality atmost $dr^{\epsilon}$ for some constant $d > 0$ and some $\epsilon \in (0,1)$?

Comment: What if you take $u_i=1$ for all $i$ ?

Comment: Doubt it will work for all instances of $Gij$! The formula depends on $Gij$ as well. Try $s=3$,$r=2$ and all $Gij=1$. You will get $0$.

Comment: hold on I made a mistake.

Comment: Thankyou. I meant $1+1=0$ and $1+1+1=1$. I understand the folly that $1\vee 1=1$. Corrected now.

Comment: You mean $a \otimes b = 1 \iff a=b$ (and not $a=b=1$) ?

Comment: no I want $0 \otimes 0 = 0$ and hence the relation.

Comment: So it is the same as an AND and my first comment remains...

Comment: Let $Gij=1$ for $i=1,2$ and $j=1,2,3$. For each $j$, then $u1\otimes G1j = 1$ and $u1\otimes G1j \oplus u2\otimes G2j = 1 \oplus 1 =0$. So $\otimes_{j=1}^{3}0=0$. We do not have valuation to $1$.

Comment: Your first comment came from my 'XOR' being wrong.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't this just solving the linear equation $\mathbf{uG}=\mathbf{1}$ over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_2$? If so, you could just use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Take $r$ is even and/or $s>r$.